# Elasticsearch only use filtered query

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my Laravel app, and I need to do a search query that only contains filters and no "text search" but I am not sure on how to write it.

Is this OK

```
$query = [
   'filtered' => [
      'filter'=> [
         'bool' => [
            'must' => [
               [ 'range' => [
                  'price' => [
                     'lte' => 9000
                  ]
               ]
               ],
            ],
         ]
      ],
   ],
];
```

or must I also use match_all eg:

```
$query = [
   'filtered' => [
   'query' => [
       'match_all' => []
    ],
      'filter'=> [
         'bool' => [
            'must' => [
               [ 'range' => [
                  'price' => [
                     'lte' => 9000
                  ]
               ]
               ],
            ],
         ]
      ],
   ],
];
```

What I want is to only use a filtered bool query without text search.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to only use filters without text search in elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989479/is-it-possible-to-only-use-filters-without-text-search-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are exactly the same.

Comment: What does 'query' => [
       'match_all' => []
    ], do?

Comment: It matches all documents but if you remove `query` and only have `filter`, the meaning still does not change.