# Is it possible to only use filters without text search in elasticsearch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my Laravel app, and I need to do a search query that only contains filters and no "text search" but I am not sure on how to write it.

**Must I use match_all** eg:

```
$query = [
   'filtered' => [
   'query' => [
       'match_all' => []
    ],
      'filter'=> [
         'bool' => [
            'must' => [
               [ 'range' => [
                  'price' => [
                     'lte' => 9000
                  ]
               ]
               ],
            ],
         ]
      ],
   ],
];
```

Or like this:

```
$query = [
   'filtered' => [
      'filter'=> [
         'bool' => [
            'must' => [
               [ 'range' => [
                  'price' => [
                     'lte' => 9000
                  ]
               ]
               ],
            ],
         ]
      ],
   ],
];
```

What I want is to only use a filtered bool query without text search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if you don't specify the `query` part in your filtered query, a match_all query is used by default. Quoting the [doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) :

> If a query is not specified, it defaults to the match_all query. This
>   means that the filtered query can be used to wrap just a filter, so
>   that it can be used wherever a query is expected.

Your second query should do the job : filters must be wrapped either in `filtered` ([doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)) or `constant_score` ([doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html)) queries to be used.

If the scoring part isn't useful for you, you can stick to the `filtered` query.

Last thing : you don't have to nest your filter in a `bool` filter, unless you want to combine it with other(s) filter(s). In your demo case, you can write directly :

```
$query = [
   'filtered' => [
      'filter'=> [
         'range' => [
             'price' => [
                'lte' => 9000
             ]
          ]
      ]
   ]
];
```

Hope this will be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! Then I will go with my 2nd query. I do have multiple filters inside the bool. I just stripped out some and forgot to remove the bool as well for this example :)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually exactly the same thing since if a query is not specified in the clause it defaults to using the match_all query.

While in query context, if you need to use a filter without a query (for instance, to match all emails in the inbox), you can just omit the query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter":   { "term": { "folder": "inbox" }}
        }
    }
}
```

If a query is not specified it defaults to using the match_all query, so the preceding query is equivalent to the following:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query":    { "match_all": {}},
            "filter":   { "term": { "folder": "inbox" }}
        }
    }
}
```

Check here the official documentation: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_combining_queries_with_filters.html

Comment: Cheers for you explanation